# SQL Server MS, change user for Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

I'm using a VPN to access a remote SQL Server. Normally I would run SSMS on my machine and use SQL Server Login for access. However, this server is set up to allow in only a particular user using Windows Authentication. I can access the DB by RDPing to that server and using SSMS on that machine, but is there any other way to do it from SSMS on my local machine?

Comment: I operate like that, so long as your VPN is using the windows credentials used to access SQL Server, you setup a connection to the database using windows authentication, and it will show your local windows username, but when it connects it converts it to the VPN username.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

1. open up a command line window - cmd.exe
2. do the following:  `runas /user:<domain>\<alias> cmd.exe`
3. enter your password when prompted
4. do the following: `ssms.exe`

it should now launch SSMS.exe under the account in #2 above.